# Angular + Firestore Accessing Data Efficiently For Html

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Angular and Firestore. I'm trying to retrieve an array object at path

```
Users/UMmmmqcfBlUoEjihfFQQutpDu9A3/events
```

[image: User Collection]

and then use every id in that array object to retrieve specific objects at path

```
Events/id
```

[image: Events Collection]

I currently have queried for all users with the id of the currentuser (returns one user) and then retrieved the array and iterated through it and retrieved each event... but I don't know how to display it in html 
[image]

{{ event.capacity }}, {{ event.end }}, etc.

Any help would be great, even suggestions about restructuring data. I'm thinking that Firestore references may be helpful, but I'm not sure how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to me like it is in your component.ts, in which case it might be easiest if you simply assign that result to a variable.

So for example you could create a variable:

```
events: any;
```

then down where you get the events data just assign it to the aforementioned variable and you can then reference that variable in the html.

```
this.events = doc.data();
```

then in your component.html you can do what you want with the data:

```
<p>{{ event.capacity }}</p>
```

hope that helps.